# Что такое ZipEntry?

Tags: java, zip, path, архивация, ziparchive

Я недавно изучаю Java и столкнулся с архивацией/разархивацией данных. Пожалуйста объясните, чем по своей сути является объект ZipEntry? Что он делает, я примерно понимаю: служит для отделения одного файла в архиве от остальных, но чем он сам является? Ведь у нас есть Path, который хранит хранит путь, а чем занимается ZipEntry? Имеет в себе байты?
И почему после считывания ZipEntry необходимо отдельно считывать байты из ZipInputStream?

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(zipFile);
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZipEntry` это по сути некий байтовый массив, грубо говоря, содержит общую информацию о записи, заголовком к которой он является: имя, размер, время, метод архивации, чексум и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее [здесь](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/packages/zip/ZipEntry.html)

Comment: Спасибо, прояснилось кое-что. А для директорий ZipEntry не требуется? У меня был код (сейчас не найду к сожалению), где возникала ошибка при попытки архивации директорий. Т.е. грубо говоря, я правильно понимаю, что если мы заархивируем директорию с единственным файлом a.txt, то в зипфайле будет только один ZipEntry, в том числе с информацией о родительской директории? Или два - один с информацией о файле, а другой с информацией о директории?